# Get remote page title from url in foreach

Tags: php, curl

How can I return titles of sites in foreach, codeigniter.
The code works, but takes too long to load.

```
<?php 
    foreach ($links->result() as $value) :
        $url = $value->lnkUrl;
        $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $web_link = "http://".$domain;

        $str = file_get_contents($web_link);

        if(strlen($str) > 0) {
            preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
            echo "<span class='directi_web'>". $title[1] ."</span>";
        } else {
            echo "<span class='directi_web'></span>";
        }

    endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: This code probably takes too long because the remote sites take a long time to respond or send a large amount of data. You should primarily avoid running such updates to often.

Comment: can you show me how to do this?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on using a database like mysql with php. This platform is for specific questions/problems.